# Solving for $g$ in a quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[is there a way to get that g = ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrdEd.png)

I want to get the g out . Getting nasty results like 
2h = g*g - g . I'm stuck . Is there a way to find square root of g*g -g or is there any other solution . Thank you

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate. Do you mean solve for $g$ in terms of $h$?

Comment: What's the difference between g and $g$?

Comment: sorry it means g * g

Answer (score 2):

$g^2-g-2h=0$. This is called a quadratic equation and there is a standard formula for finding a solution to this type of equation.

If the equation is $ax^2+bx+c=0$, the solutions are given by:

$x = \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and $x = \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.

In your case, $a=1, b=-1, c=-2h$, so the solutions are:

$g = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1+8h}}{2}$ and $g = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1+8h}}{2}$.

You will have to constrain the problem further to determine if any or both of the above solutions are valid.

Comment: Now i'm in home . Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Multiply out to obtain the quadratic:

$$h = {g^2 - g \over 2}$$

so $$g^2 - 2 h - g = 0$$.

Use the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula):

$$g = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1\pm \sqrt{8 h+1} \right)$$

Comment: that is what i was looking for , could you please explain this shortly